# Trying to delete white space in Facebook Like box

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I a working on a client's website and decided to add a "Facebook Like Box" ([example](http://www.ordwaybuildingsupply.com/Joomla_258/)). I was working in the Facebook Developers page. I am a Joomla developer (2.5x platform) I am trying to figure out how to delete the white space from the title of the like box WAY down to where my pictures are... Any suggestions on how to do this or where I need to go into Facebook to correct this??

I tried to re-size the height, BUT once I did that to make it smaller, it cut off my pictures.

Your help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: ok, stack overflow does not understand the URLs so you'll have to copy and paste or use the short link.

That's a frame, short link: http://on.fb.me/152cjgH

`http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?api_key=&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D18%23cb%3Df108e873a75ab52%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ordwaybuildingsupply.com%252Ff211d31607a9c7e%26domain%3Dwww.ordwaybuildingsupply.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&height=558&header=false&show_faces=true&stream=true&width=200&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhome.php%3Fclk_loc%3D5%23!%2FOBS75%3Ffref%3Dts&colorscheme=light`

The big white space is the stream so change the values you're requesting, namely

remove `&stream=true`

and change `&height=558` to `&height=300` or something

http://on.fb.me/152co4e >
`http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?api_key=&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D18%23cb%3Df108e873a75ab52%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.ordwaybuildingsupply.com%252Ff211d31607a9c7e%26domain%3Dwww.ordwaybuildingsupply.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&height=300&header=false&show_faces=true&width=200&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhome.php%3Fclk_loc%3D5%23!%2FOBS75%3Ffref%3Dts&colorscheme=light`